# Time in objective c returns as 0

Tags: objective-c, time, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I'm working on a counter, and this is my code to find the time.

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [start timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSLog(@"%f",timeInterval);
```

This is what it returns over and over again.

```
2014-03-08 17:59:46.834 Time[67444:303] 0.000000
```

What is happening with this?

Comment: What do you expect when you take the difference between "now" and "now"?  At most you might have a millisecond difference or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `timeIntervalSinceNow` on an object that represents a very very close value to "now". Since you print in float, the value is rounded down to lower precision and you get 0.

Are you sure you didn't mean `timeIntervalSince1970`?

`NSTimeInterval` is defined as a `double`. If you need precision above float, try printing as double using `%ld`. If you need even more precision, look into `mach_absolute_time()`.

Comment: Note also that you could use the good ol' `time(NULL)` if you just need an integer

Comment: I've tried timeIntervalSince1970, and timeIntervalSinceDate and timeIntervalSince1970 is the only one that returns a number, but one too big.

Comment: @CuriousPaths What are you trying to achieve? `NSTimeInterval` is in seconds.

Comment: I want the time in seconds since the program starts, but all it says is 0.00000.

Comment: @CuriousPaths Then you should move `NSDate *start = [NSDate date];` to `application:didLaunchWithOptions:`.

Comment: I don't see anything like that, is it because I'm running Xcode for OS X development?

Comment: @CuriousPaths Yes, my example was for iOS, but there is an equivalent method for OS X (not sure what it is).